# Is there any way to get URL from Google Chrome toast notification on windows 10?

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to get the URLs from all notifications triggered by Google Chrome.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener

This is the document to explain how to get all user notifications on Windows 10.
But here I can't find any good solution to get the URL from Google Chrome notification. Could anyone help me?

User notifications

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The URL from Google Chrome should be an [Attribution text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=xml#attribution-text).

Currently, there is no APIs used to read the `AttributionText` property from a [Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.notification?view=winrt-19041) instance in a `UserNotication` which is read from `UserNotificationListener.GetNotificationsAsync()` method.